# BigQuery SQL exclude rows where certain values appear in different columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table:

```
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|      id     |     value_1      |  value_2    |     value_3      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------| 
|       1     |         10       |      11     |         111      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       2     |         20       |      22     |         222      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       3     |         30       |      33     |         333      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       4     |         40       |      44     |         444      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       5     |         50       |      55     |         555      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       6     |         60       |      66     |         666      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
|       7     |         60       |     null    |        null      |
|-------------|------------------|-------------|------------------|
```

I would like to exclude rows which contain

- `value_1` like 10 and 20
- `value_2` like 33 and 44
- `value_3` like 444 and 555

I've tried code like this:

```
select *
from (
    select *
    from (
        select *
        from `schema.table`
        where value_3 not in ('444', '555'))
    where value_2 not in ('33', '44'))
where value_1 not in ('10', '20'))
```

and also liked this:

```
select *
from `schema.tabele`
where id not in (
  select distinct id
  from `schema.tabele`
  where id not in (
    select distinct id
    from `schema.tabele`
    where id not in (
      select distinct id
      from `schema.tabele`
      where value_3 not in ('444', '555')))
  and value_2 not in ('33', '44'))
and value_1 not in ('10', '20'))
```

I am not getting the good results.. Could you explain why?

Comment: Please describe what "not getting the good results" means.  What results are you getting?  What results do you want?

Comment: I am saving this table, which results show be just the last row in this case and then doin select * from `schema.result_table` where value_1 = '60' and it doesn't return anything

Comment: . . Could any of the columns you are comparing have `NULL` values?  They fail comparisons.  (Your sample data doesn't have `NULL` values.)

Comment: Yes, they do! I know, the sample data doesn't.. Didn't know that might be an issue :(

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have amended the table so that there are some `NULL` values like in my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems overly complicated.  How about using `and`?

```
select *
from `schema.table`
where value_3 not in ('444', '555') and
      value_2 not in ('33', '44') and
      value_1 not in ('10', '20')
```

EDIT:

If you need to handle `NULL` values, then you need to be explicit:

```
select *
from `schema.table`
where (value_3 not in ('444', '555') or value_3 is null) and
      (value_2 not in ('33', '44') or value_2 is null) and
      (value_1 not in ('10', '20') or value_1 is null)
```

Comment: I tried like this but it also doesn't return correct results.. But it should work, right? I mean as far as SQL works?

Comment: @NorahJones - can you clearly explain what does "doesn't return correct results" means!? with exact example of input data, output and expected output, so we can identify the issue

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I have amended the table so that there are some NULL values like in my table, I cannot provide the orginial table - it's confidential

Answer (score 1):

below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select *
from `project.dataset.table`
where not ( 
  ifnull(value_3, 'x') in ('444', '555')
  or ifnull(value_2, 'x') in ('33', '44')
  or ifnull(value_1, 'x') in ('10', '20')
  )
```